# 사흘 있으면: how 면 is used in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

Could anyone explain the usage of 면 in the sentence below? 
Also how would you translate it?

사흘 있으면 명절이므로 길이 막힐 거다.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when there is the form [time period] + 있으면, the implied meaning is "After [time period]" or "(With)in [time period]."

So, "사흘 있으면" means "In three days."

The full sentence translated means

> "Because it will be a holiday in three days, the roads will be jammed."

The fuller form really is [time period] + 있으면 Noun + 이다, meaning "In [amount of time], it will be [Noun]."

Comment: The verb `있다` usually means `to exist`, but here it is showing its special meaning off: `to elapse`. It's often used along with following `-으면` or `-으니` for this meaning. `사흘만 있으면 추석이다.` `그로부터 한 달 있으니 눈이 내리기 시작했다.`

Answer (score 2):

"~~면", is almost means "~~, then"

- "내가 가면" => I go, then => when I go,
- "바람이 불면" => wind blows, then => when wind blows,
- "사흘 있으면" => three days, then => In three days,